# ADB doesn't work, device offline, ADBD gives segmentation fault

Tags: android, adb

I have a ViewSonic VB100a tablet, and I'm trying to use ADB for app debugging.

When I start the device, ADB works fine. After I disconnect, wait for a while and reconnect, ADB gives a "device offline" error when trying any adb command (devices, shell, none work).

Using Terminal Emulator I found out that the md5 hash of the file /sbin/adbd changes. These are the hashes of the files.

Working: 06507f51e43a4632507dba159a5cbd13

Not working: a2ff86b348e615cce5603cd4761089ef

What could cause this problem? A broken memory chip? I don't think so since rebooting Android restores it.

Thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT: [Here's a link](http://tobiass.eu/adbd.zip) to both the binaries with MD5 sums

EDIT 2: I've made a simple app that copies the good adbd from my sd card to /sbin and restarts it. It's not the most convenient way, but it's better than restarting the device all the time :)

Comment: Could be bad RAM, i.e. when you run md5sum you're reading out of the in-memory file cache rather than off disk.  If that's the case I'd expect you to be seeing lots of other failures though.

Comment: @fadden I don't assume this is the problem since it occurs regularly.

Comment: This looks like a hardware problem definitely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes the changes in adbd, but have you tried this?

```
$ adb kill-server
```

This command will kill the adbd and if you do adb shell after that it will restart adbd.

Comment: Problem is with the /sbin/adbd binary on the device. When I run it in the terminal it gives me a Segmentation Fault. There's nothing wrong with ADB on my PC, works with other Androids.